# In django-rest-auth, the password reset confirm URL doesn't work--is it missing arguments?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

If you look at urlpatterns in `django.contrib.auth.urls`, the `password_reset_confirm` URL takes `uidb64` and `token` params, which makes sense--when clicked on, this will identify the user resetting the password.  However, `django-rest-auth`'s `rest_password_reset_confirm` URL doesn't take any arguments: it just goes to `password/reset/confirm/`.  How can it work?  I get the following 500 error when submitting my email to reset my password, and I'm not surprised--the error makes sense:

```
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'uidb64': 'NA', u'token': u'4lj-65cd7b4219c9206126b4'}' not found.
```

What I don't understand is it seems like such a basic thing that I must be doing something wrong--otherwise everyone using `django-rest-auth` would get this error because the arguments are clearly missing in the URL definition.  Has anyone else experienced it and if so, did you update the URL to fix it?

UPDATE: It looks like `django-rest-auth`, by default, simply uses native Django's `contrib/admin/templates/registration/password_reset_email.html` template.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out there's a simple [one-line fix](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/issues/205)--add this to your base url patterns:

```
url(r'^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used following once in my template:

`{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token  %}`

And, it works fine. Can you please show your template include structure?

Comment: Thanks @Sijan, the default Django template is used--I updated my question.  The problem is not the template here, but `django-rest-auth`'s urlpatterns.